# Can we avoid confusion over using "let" as a quantifier?

Tags: undergraduate-education, mathematical-pedagogy, logic, vocabulary

I've encountered the following misunderstanding.
I pose a question (to undergraduates in the U.S.), for example:

> Let $P$ be a polygon of $n$ vertices.
> Is it true that every triangulation of $P$
> has the same number of triangles?

This question depends on what constitutes a "triangulation," but
assume the student know that. The answer is *Yes*:
every triangulation of $P$ consists of $n-2$ triangles.

Here is the problem I encounter. The students apparently
don't understand that "Let $P$ be a polygon" means,
let your mind run over all possible polygons, so $P$ is
an "arbitrary" polygon, in that it can be anything that
fits the definition of a polygon (which the students also know). They wonder, well, maybe $P$ is a convex polygon,
and should I answer specific to convex polygons?

This example doesn't quite illustrate the problem because
the answer is always *Yes*. But when the answer is sometimes *Yes*, sometimes *No*, they seem to get confused
over the quantifier. I think it may come down to the
meaning of the phrase: "Let $A$ be a $B$." Let $p$ be
a point in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$—meaning
*any* point in the plane, an "arbitrary" point in the plane. Let $P$ be a polygon, meaning *any* polygon.
Let $T$ be a triangulation of a set of $n$ points.
Does every triangulation of $n$ points have the same number of triangles? (*No*, not always.)

**Have you encountered this confusion in your teaching? If so, how do you circumvent it?**

Comment: Reminds me of this question I asked: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/inability-to-work-with-an-arbitrary-mathematical-object  Perhaps we need to be more explicit/verbose with "let"! Would students be less inclined to this confusion if we said, for instance, "Suppose P is any polygon, with no other assumptions about its properties"?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what "Let P be a polygon" means outside our classroom? @BrendanW.Sullivan

Comment: I should say that this confusion arose in written questions, not verbal explanations, where it is easy to elaborate as @BrendanW.Sullivan suggests.

Comment: @ChrisCunningham Yes, exactly. But it seems like maybe the problem is students don't realize that the single word "let" for us means all of that other stuff. I'm recommending that we spell it out for them a lot. Emphasize that idea in class so that, on a written problem like in OP, part of the question is assessing their understanding that "Let P be a polygon" means to consider all possible polygons.

Comment: My initial thought was that "convex" was intended, because omissions such as this are common (sometimes on purpose, sometimes just overlooked), and in my opinion to avoid having a gotcha question you'd want to say something like "polygon (convex or not)", unless prior context or reader exposure was that non-convex polygons arose often enough that your intended audience should be thinking about them (which I can't judge based only on what you've posted). So regarding "*how do you circumvent it*", I would say by anticipating common/expected assumptions unless you're specifically testing that.

Comment: This is expressed in the old joke about how different fields cope with being locked in a jail cell with a sealed tin can of food. The physicist attempts to ballistically throw the can at the correct angle and velocity at the wall to overcome its tolerances and achieve catastrophic loss of structural integrity. The chemist takes samples of everything nearby and attempts to synthesize an adequate solvent. The economist researches how much money the jailer must be paid to secure a release. The mathematician calmly asserts, "Let P be a can opener....".

Comment: Have you tried saying "suppose $P$ is a polygon" or "assume $P$ is a polygon" instead?

Comment: @RobertColumbia: That's an amusing joke because it only works if you really **do** get confused between ∀-quantification and ∃-instantiation.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold: In some FOL formalizations, free variables are allowed, in which case "assume" is actually fine because ∀intro for restricted quantification essentially corresponds to that. However, in standard English, and conventional mathematical language, "assume P is a polygon" is inappropriate, but "assume P is some polygon" and "suppose P is a polygon" are fine. But for good pedagogy, I stand by the solution detailed in my answer.

Comment: Interesting. I would expect them not to know what triangulation is. Try googling it, the default answer is, "Triangulation is when a toxic or manipulative person, often a person with strong narcissistic traits, brings a third person into their relationship in order to remain in control." Not to mention, they answer a "what" question with "when".

Comment: @RustyCore: I had taught these students what is a *triangulation*, before the "Let $P$ be a polygon" problem became evident.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Many logicians that I have spoken to have concurred with my assessment that this is an issue of the misleading use of "let". Many teachers use this word in two **very different** and **incompatible** ways. The first is universal quantification, as in your example. The second is existential instantiation, as in "Let $z = \exp(x+y)$. Then [blah blah] about $z$.".

The solution is simple. Do not use the bare word "let" for universal quantification, because it is not even technically the most precise way of expressing the desired meaning in English. Here are some much preferable alternatives:

- Take/consider any polygon $P$. ...
- Let $P$ be any given polygon. Then ...

The key word is "**any**", which is needed to precisely convey the universal quantification. If you want to express universal quantification in a single sentence, you can use the following:

- Given any polygon $P$, ...
- For every polygon $P$, ...

Note that the English word "any" behaves differently from "every". For example, "If for any $x∈S$ we have $f(x)∈T$, then ..." actually means "For every $x∈S$, if $f(x)∈T$ then ..." and not "If for every $x∈S$ we have $f(x)∈T$, then ...". So to minimize confusion it is better to stick with "for every" in single-sentence universal quantification.

I often hear the excuse that people have been using "let" in the confusing way for so long already, and that students have to learn to interpret it anyway. That is an excuse, because we have no reason not to use **precise** words in our teaching. As you yourself pointed out *emphatically*, using the word "any" would make things so much clearer. So we should use it! After students have acquired a proper grasp of logical reasoning (and not before that), facilitated by precise teaching, we can then tell students that some textbooks actually use "let" in the confusing manner, and they will have no trouble with it.

Related to this, students understand quantifiers far better when they are explained in terms of [game semantics](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1782071/21820). Similarly for teaching [structural induction](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10034/1550). These are also perfectly in line with the use of the phrasing "given any ...".

Comment: Agreed.  But I would personally lean towards *arbitrary* rather than *any* as it is a more mathematically precise word.

Comment: @MatthewDaly: Yes, you can use "given an arbitrary polygon $P$", but it is not any more mathematically precise than using "given any". This is standard English. If we do not want to use English, there is always "∀".

Comment: @MatthewDaly: There is also another reason to stick to "any", because it is more concise. Consider: "Given any $a,b∈\mathbb{R}$ with $a≤b$, and any continuous $f : [a,b]→\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a) ≤ 0 ≤ f(b)$, there is some $c∈[a,b]$ such that $f(c) = 0$. Similarly for theorems involving more universally quantified variables. =)

Comment: I think this answer makes a good point (+1). One small quibble, though, is that it does not work with mathematical symbols. Consider for instance the following example: "Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi)$ and $r \in [1,\infty)$. Then ..." If one insists on using "any" in all those cases, this becomes e.g.: "Let $z$ be any complex number, let $\theta$ be any number in the interval $[-\pi,\pi)$ and let $r$ be any element of $[0,\infty)$. Then ..." If one does this often, it becomes a bit annoying.

Comment: But I agree that it might be a good idea to do it in teaching until the students got  used to logical reasoning in mathematical arguments.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Actually, my answer **does** work with symbols! "Take/consider/given any $z∈ℂ$"... I thought I said quite clearly that I discourage the use of "let" for ∀-quantification?

Comment: @user21820: Well, you said that you discourage the "use [of] the bare word 'let' for universal quantification" and suggested "Let ... be any ..." as a preferable alternative. I agree that your other alternative suggestion "Take/Consider any ..." works well with symbols (thanks for pointing that out; I did indeed overlook this).  In contrast to the "Let ... any ..." it has another small disadvantage, though: if ones has many objects in a theorem and thus splits their quantification into several sentences, it sounds a bit strange to use "consider" or "take" in several subsequent sentences, [...]

Comment: [...] while I don't see the same issues with using "Let ..." several times. At least for me, "consider" or "take" generates a slightly different connotation which does not go well with using it in an "accumulative" manner. (My overall point is that there are indeed some sensible reasons, apart from old habits, to use the bare word "Let" for universal quantification.  But as I said, I agree with you that it might cause confusion for beginners and it might thus be a good idea to avoid it, at least in the beginning.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Thanks for your comments! There are two issues you might be referring to. (1) If you have a bunch of objects in a contiguous ∀-quantification block, then I find repeatition of "let ... any ..." just as 'unnatural' in English, and I don't even notice mathematicians using it repeatedly. Usually, one can say it in a single sentence: "Take any a,b⊆ℝ with a<b, and any continuous function f : [a,b]→ℝ. If f(a) < 0 < f(b), then ..."

Comment: (2) In a non-formal proof, one uses extra words and varies the English to make it 'flow': "Take any linear order ⟨L,<⟩ such that ... Let [∃elim] C be ... Then ... Now consider any sequence ... We can see that ...". Indeed, in a proof "take" and "consider" are a bit strange to use more than once each, so we can use "for every/any/each" for all the inner quantifications, which usually have much more limited scope. =)

Comment: “Many teachers use [the] word [“let”] in two very different and incompatible ways.” I don’t see how the example you chose are incompatible. “Let $x$ be a real number” and “let $x$ be the real number $\pi$” are two sides of the same coin: both are universal quantification, just that the latter one has an additional condition to satisfy…

Comment: @MacRance: Although the example I gave in the post may be viewed in the way you suggest, the ordinary mathematician does not *actually* view it your way, and it is not the case in general either. For example, when a mathematician says "Let $f : ℕ→ℝ$ be defined by the recursive relation ...", he/she **must** use ∃elim on the appropriate instantiation of the recursion theorem. There is logically no other possible way.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to what has been said:

1. These sentences in a proof are equivalent:

   - > Let $P_n$ be a polygon of $n$ vertices.
   - Let $P_n$ be an **arbitrary** polygon of $n$ vertices.
   - Let $P_n$ be an **arbitrary** polygon and suppose that $P_n$ has $n$ vertices.
   - Let $P_n$ be an **arbitrary** polygon such that $P_n$ has $n$ vertices.

   The adjective ‘arbitrary’ (alternatively: ‘**any**’) is frequently tacit—as in the OP's given sentence—as the intended meaning can be inferred from the context. So, as suggested by user21820, an immediate solution to the issue raised by the OP of clarifying Mathematical English is to not omit it from the sentence.
2. Concluding the proof and asserting its result $\psi(P_n):$

   - **For each** polygon $P_n$ of $n$ vertices, $\psi(P_n).$
   - $\forall P_n{\in}\{x \mid x \text{ is a polygon of $n$ vertices}\}\:\:\psi(P_n).$

   This implicitly invokes [Universal Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) to **generalise a representative (any $P_n$) to the universal (each $P_n$).**
3. The word ‘let’ per se does not connote universal (or existential) quantification; it merely signifies that a definition/restriction/value is to be assigned.

   However, having answered such questions on Mathematics.Stackexchange

   > My issue comes with statements like "Let $x$ be an integer". I really do not know how I should intuitively interpret such a statement.  Should I interpret it like how I interpret "Suppose $x$ is an integer"?

   > What does "Let $G$ be a group" even mean?

   I agree with user21820 that the more specific phrasing

   - *Consider* an arbitrary polygon $P_n$ of $n$ vertices

   is probably clearer.
4. Here's a comparison of the various translations of $$∀x{\in}F\; \psi(x).$$

   - “**For all** elements $x$ in $F,\,\psi(x)$ holds” sometimes sounds like the property $\psi$ might belong to $F$ as a whole rather than to its individual members: “for all members of the family, they have a house” (1 house in total? or 5?). Contrast with “for each member of the family, they have a house” (definitely 5 houses in total). ([“For all $x$” is Mathlish.](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/26771/372))
   - “**For every** element $x$ in $F,\,\psi(x)$ holds”, despite ‘every’ too having a collective sense, says that the property $\psi$ is common to the members of $F.$
   - “**For each** element $x$ in $F,\,\psi(x)$ holds” directly attributes the property $\psi$ to individual members of $F.$
   - “**For any** element $x$ in $F,\,\psi(x)$ holds” doesn't strongly communicate that the property $\psi$ belongs to each and every member of $F;$ nevertheless, “for any $x$” typically means “**given an arbitrary** $x$”, which, logically, is synonymous with “**for every** $x$” and “**for each** $x$”.
5. In any case, when writing and teaching mathematics, the word ‘**any**’ should be used judiciously, because its meaning alternates between ‘every’ and ‘some’, or could be ambiguous.

   - “***If any*** intruder enters, the alarm will sound.”

     Here, ‘if any’ means ‘***if some***’ instead of ‘if every’.
   - “He does ***not*** have ***any*** pet.”

     Here, ‘not any’ means ‘***not some***’ instead of ‘not every’.
   - Wikipedia's [definition of set disjointedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets): “A collection of two or more sets is disjoint ***if any*** two distinct sets of the collection are disjoint.”

     Are three sets are disjoint ***if every*** pair of distinct sets is disjoint or ***if some*** pair of distinct sets is disjoint? It turns out from reading between the lines two sections down that Wikipedia intends the ‘if every’ reading, even as the ‘if some’ reading is probably more idiomatic. No wonder [authors disagree between these two contrasting definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4012997/21813)!

Comment: I would like to add to this excellent answer one additional comment: students commonly use the word "random" as a synonym for "arbitrary" (e.g., "Suppose $P$ is some random polygon...")  This should be anticipated, because in common language "random" is often used to mean "arbitrary, non-specific, generic".  ("This random guy came up to me on the street today and said...")  However, this usage should be discouraged whenever it occurs in a mathematical context, as "random" has a technical meaning  in mathematical probability.

Comment: @mweiss Thanks! Allow me to add: [Two aspects of randomness](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3893774/21813) and
 [Arbitrary vs. Random](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2529446/21813).